# Reading a JSON Object from a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

Alright, so I'm making a quick edit on an exiting application, but I have never touched Grails before, so I apologize if this is not explanatory enough.

So, I have a JS controller for an set of input that needs parsing on the page.  I also have a Grails function that need to take in the parsed data from the Javascript file.  I've saved everything in a JSON object in the Javascript, and I need to pass it to the Grails function to be processed.  Any ideas how?  I've tried to find answers, but all of the answers go from Grails to JS not the other way around.

Comment: The JS controller is a JSON object? You simply need to get properties from it?

Comment: Add a sample self explanatory code representing what you have done and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use jQuery. In your javascript code, you serialize your data to JSON:

```
var parameters = {
    a : "a_value",
    b : [1,2,3],
    c : {
        d : 'd_value'
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    data : JSON.stringify(parameters),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'POST'
})
```

then, in your controller, you can have an access to your data:

```
def parameters = request.JSON
//example access to parameters
assert parameters.a == 'a_value'
assert parameters.b == [1,2,3]
assert parameters.c.d == 'd_value'
```

Hope that should help!

Comment: Alright, so I am quite inexperienced in web development.  I assume it's url: "localhost:8080" while i'm doing this on my own machine?